# How can I connect a (wireless) keyboard to a Sony Bravia TV?

Tags: tv

Is it possible to connect a USB keyboard - in this case a Microsoft Wireless keyboard - to a Sony Bravia TV without having to go through another computer?

When I plug the USB receiver into the TV the TV shows a message 'USB Device Not Supported'.

Comment: What TV model is that ? Maybe it doesn't support keyboards, no matter if they're wireless or not.

Comment: This is a bit of a longshot but... connect the keyboard to a PC and  check the IntelliType application and keyboard support page for a firmware (not driver) update. Who knows? Maybe they patched something to make it work.

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online manual for that make/model of TV does not mention anything about using keyboards (wireless or wired) hooked to the system. You can contact Sony directly, but I do not believe the TV firmware has been written to understand keyboards.

Source: http://docs.esupport.sony.com/imanual/NA/EN/EX720_UC/index.html